# Why does C++ accept multiple prefixes but not postfixes for a variable

Tags: c++, increment, prefix, decrement, postfix-operator

While looking into [Can you have a incrementor and a decrementor on the same variable in the same statement in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679258/can-you-have-a-incrementor-and-a-decrementor-on-the-same-variable-in-the-same-st#comment15483521_11679258)

I  discovered that you can have several prefix increment/decrement operators on a single variable, but only one postfix

ex:

```
++--++foo; // valid
foo++--++; // invalid
--foo++;   // invalid
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the fact that in C++ (but not C), the result of `++x` is a lValue, meaning it is assignable, and thus chain-able.

However, the result of `x++` is NOT an lValue, instead it is a prValue, meaning it cannot be assigned to, and thus cannot be chained.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ language prefix increment/decrement operators return *lvalues*, while postfix ones return *rvalues*. Meanwhile, all modifying operators require lvalue arguments. This means that the result of prefix increment/decrement can be passed on to any other additional operator that requires an lvalue argument (including additional increments/decrements).

For the very same reason in C++ you can write code like this

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &++i;
```

which will increment `i` and make `p` point to `i`. Unary `&` requires lvalue operand, which is why it will work with the result of prefix `++` (but not with postfix one).

Expressions with multiple built-in prefix increments/decrements applied to the same object produce *undefined behavior*, but they are nevertheless well-formed (i.e. "compilable").

Expressions like `++foo--` are invalid because in C++ postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix ones. Braces can change that. For example, `(++foo)--` is a well-formed expression, albeit leading to undefined behavior again.

Comment: Can you show some documentation that says that the result is undefined? Seems to me like it should be completely well-defined (evaluated right-to-left outwards).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII UB because *(C++11, 1.9p15) "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either anotherside effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: The well-known paragraph 5/4 in C++ language specification (C++98, C++03). It is illegal (in UB sense) to modify the same object twice without intervening *sequence point* (SP). C++ does not define order of evaluation for built-in operators without SP. There's no such thing as "evaluated left-to-right" in C++ without SP. Any orderings require intervening SP. There's no sequence point in `++--foo`, hence the behavior is undefined. C++11 uses a different formal approach to sequencing, but the basic principle remains the same.